# How to implement statistics for the length of continued fractions of a result on MATHEMATICA

Tags: probability-or-statistics, number-theory, continued-fractions

After successfully generating the reduced fraction of two coprime in interval (0,1] with the following;

```
l={};
For[ b=1, b<20,b++For[a= 1, a < b, a++, AppendTo[l,Simplify[a/b]]]];
L=DeleteDuplicates[l];
L
```

Now, I want to implement the statistics for the length of the corresponding continued fractions, But I have no idea how to go about this using MATHEMATICA

I will be very happy to be helped...

Comment: Does `Map[Length @* ContinuedFraction, L]` give you a start? Also `L = FareySequence[19][[2 ;; -2]]` seems equivalent and shorter.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have some questions: what kind of continued fraction expansion is used here? I think, it can't be the ordinary one, since the lengths of the continued fractions of 1/2 and 2/3, as I understand, are both equal to 2.

Comment: Doesn't the first line under the "Details" of the documentation page describe the CF completely? $1/2 = {\bf0} + 1/{\bf2}$, $2/3 = {\bf0} + 1 /({\bf1} + 1/{\bf2})$, where bold-faced parts are returned by `ContinuedFraction`. I don't think the CFs of $1/2$ and $2/3$ have the same length, if the numerators are always $1$. One might or might not count the initial $\bf0$ in the length, I suppose, but it seems to be the standard CF that I'm used to.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the support just a little more question, what do the entries "2" in L mean if not the length of the continued fraction decomposition? Is there a way I could understand what the code are doing? I will be glad to understand it thanks

Comment: If you mean the twos in `[[2 ;; -2]]`, they signify the range of parts to take, 2 = the second part to -2 = the second from the end; see `Part` and `Span` in the docs.  If you mean the twos in `Map[Length@*ContinuedFraction, L]`, it means the length of the CF. E.g. `ContinuedFraction[1/3]` is `{0, 3}`, that is $0 + 1/3$, which has length 2.

Comment: @MichaelE2 But then the program is computing something else, right? 1/2 and 2/3 have continued fractions of different length. please check

Comment: Please state what you think are the continued fraction expansions of 1/2 and 2/3.

Comment: `1/2=0+1/2
1
/
2
=
0
+
1
/
2
, 2/3=0+1/(1+1/2)`

Comment: To me, the length of 0 + 1/2 (= $[0; 2]$ in [standard notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Motivation_and_notation)) is 2, and the length of 0+1/(1+1/2) (= $[0; 1, 2]$) is 3. I already went over this in [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251306/how-to-implement-statistics-for-the-length-of-continued-fractions-of-a-result-on?noredirect=1#comment629892_251306).